# Invoke external URL in struts2 Tiles definition

Tags: jsp, struts2

I would like to change /LogAnalyzer with an external URL like www.google.com:

```
<definition name="dashboard.LogAnalyzer" extends="base.definition">
    <put name="body" value="/LogAnalyzer" />
    <put name="helplink" value="../APHelp/LogAnalyzer.htm" />
    <put name="path" value="Monitors &gt; Log Analyzer" />
</definition>
```

I tried to put the URL in there but I got it appended to web app root which doesn't work.

What is the best solution for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to show external site inside your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to "statically" include the content of an external site in your site, then [grab the site content](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-url-content-in-java/) and output it in your page (take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/1654265) for more details);
2. if instead you want to "encapsulate" another site inside your own site, like having Google's homepage in a *tile* of yours, sourrounded by your header, your footer and your left bar, then what you need is not a `Tile`, is an `<iframe/>`;

   the code of your body Tile:

   ```
   <p>This is my body Tile</p>

   <iframe src="https://www.google.com/" style="width:800px; height:600px;" />
   ```

Comment: Thanks. But I would opt for second solution.
The issue is I have to use tiles. So should I create a jsp to point to ?